# Average of last 3 purchases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help to create a query to calculate the average price of last 3 purchases for each product...
like shown on this image:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Edit your question and add the table example to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this will work

```
;WITH CTE AS (
                  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Purchase DESC) AS RN
,Purchase,
,cost
   FROM   Table1
              )
SELECT *
      ,AVG(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY Product) AS Average
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN BETWEEN 1 AND 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window functions and `avg()`.  The idea is to enumerate the purchases by the purchase date and choose the most recent three for aggregation:

```
select product, avg(buyprice)
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by purchase desc) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t1
where seqnum <= 3
group by product;
```